# Make repetitive HTML with non-repetitive values

Tags: html

I have this code

```
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img
            src="/divide.png"
            alt="?"
            width="20px"
          />
        </td>
        <td>Divide</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>a24</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img
            src="/multiply.png"
            alt="?"
            width="25px"
          />
        </td>
        <td>Exponen</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>a25</td>
      </tr>
```

They are pretty repetitive HTML. Those are only 2 of the repetitive things, there are hundreds more of those.

The very bad servers are wobbling a bit with this, so I'm thinking is there a way to compact that up?

Something like this:

```
<td v1="/divide.png" v2="Divide" v3="1" v4="a24">
```

and it would return the exact same thing as

```
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img
            src="/divide.png"
            alt="?"
            width="20px"
          />
        </td>
        <td>Divide</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>a24</td>
      </tr>
```

Is it possible? If yes, how do I do it? Any programming language, javascript, PHP? I think it may be possible with javascript loops but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: "The very bad servers are wobbling a bit with this" - what does that mean? Usually, a server does not care about repetitive HTML structures

Comment: Also: yes, any server-side language could be help to generate this on the server, and JS could help to generate the markup on the client

Comment: There are thousands of lines of code because of this and it's surprisingly taking up a bit of storage from the server which should be for the images.

Comment: You want a very compact output on the server side, that means the clients have to create the html/markup and that will shift the need for resources. You can also create the html output once and cache it very long, that is probably the most easy way. And use 'gzip' compression on server side for minimum data send over the internet.

Comment: I'd suggest that you would place more of a load on the servers if they had to build the HTML from your proposed string than just loading the HTML in one hit

Comment: No, I said it was about the storage, not the load. My bad on explaining it a bit vague.

Comment: "a bit of storage" - really? That's HTML, which should be pretty compact compared to images? If this is **really** long code, you should care more about the user experience and the load on the client system that needs to display this huge table

Comment: Hmm yes, maybe the long code was the best thing haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can in do it in 2 methods

### method #1 (JS)

```js
var comWrap = document.querySelector('#wrapper table tbody')
var data = [
  [
    '/image.png',
    'this is an image',
    'Devide',
    1,
    'a16',
  ],
  [
    '/image2.png',
    'this is image2',
    'Devide2',
    2,
    'a17',
  ],
  [
    '/image3.png',
    'this is image3',
    'Devide3',
    3,
    'a316',
  ],
  [
    '/image4png',
    'this is image4',
    'Devide5',
    4,
    'a163',
  ],
  [
    '/image6png',
    'this is image6',
    'Devide5',
    5,
    'a15',
  ],
  [
    '/image6png',
    'this is an image',
    'Devide',
    6,
    'a16',
  ]
]

for(let i = 0; i < data.length;i++){
  insertRow(data[i])
}

function insertRow(arr){
  let [src, alt, name, number, info] = arr; // <--- sorting is very important
  let com = `     
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img
            src="${src}"
            alt="${alt}"
            width="20px"
          />
        </td>
        <td>${name}</td>
        <td>${number}</td>
        <td>${info}</td>
      </tr>` //<--- it's very important to add `` and not ''
  comWrap.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', com)
}

/* or you can directly loop it
for (let i = 0; i < data.length;i++){
  let [src, alt, name, number, info] =data[i];
  let com = `     
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img
            src="${src}"
            alt="${alt}"
            width="20px"
          />
        </td>
        <td>${name}</td>
        <td>${number}</td>
        <td>${info}</td>
      </tr>` //<--- it's very important to add `` and not ''
  comWrap.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', com)
}
*/
```

```css
/*not important*/

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

### method #2 (JS) but with custom HTML tags

```js
class CustomRow extends HTMLElement { // (1)
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `
      <tr>
        <td>
          <img
            src="${this.getAttribute('src')}"
            alt="${this.getAttribute('alt')}"
            width="${this.getAttribute('width')}"
          />
        </td>
        <td>${this.getAttribute('name')}</td>
        <td>${this.getAttribute('num')}</td>
        <td>${this.getAttribute('info')}</td>
      </tr>`
  }
}

customElements.define("custom-row", CustomRow); // (2)
```

```css
/*you can also select it in query selectors*/

custom-row{
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<custom-row src="/divide.png" alt="this is alt" width="20px" name="Divide" num="1" info="a16"></custom-row>
```

---

#### resources

1. https://javascript.info/custom-elements
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements
4. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements

#### browser support

https://caniuse.com/custom-elementsv1
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define#browser_compatibility
[image]

### HTML component framework

1. https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/
2. https://slimjs.com/
3. https://stenciljs.com/
4. https://github.com/hybridsjs/hybrids
5. https://github.com/lit/lit
6. https://github.com/lit/lit-element

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your guess means "component".It use a target and attribute to describe lots of html tag.All right, you can do that by js frame like vue,react and origin component or server language template engine like php smart template engine.